# Animation in android widget

Tags: animation, android-widget

Can we set animation in android widget? 
For example, i have several buttons if i press button1 they will play animation1, press button2 play animation2 and so on..
Any idea how to do this?
Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Because RemoteViews have alot of limited in view effect. So i recommend if you need a lot effect widget view, just try to make Widget yourself by extend from BroadcastReceiver

Refer this link for more:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html